# What is the best epic destiny for me?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, epic-tier

My character is an elf cleric of Melora multiclassing in ranger. He is basically a bow/ laser cleric combo. I am also planning to take the Seldarine Dedicate paragon path.

As I like to have my character planned out in advance, I have been looking at possible epic destinies and 2 seem to stand out: Demigod and Exalted Angel. 
Both seem like they would fit into my character's story quite well so I am not sure which one to take.

Demigod has the +2 to any 2 abilities as well as self-healing and unlimited encounter powers.

However, Exalted angel provides me with wings which would be useful as well as extra defenses, a cheat death feature which hurts enemies and a useful power which is an encounter/ move power (meaning I'll get more use  out of  it). What would you suggest?

**Source books:** My group is only using PHB1 and the Power books. We're using the compiled rules updates PDF from [the updates archive](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive), but we're not using the compendium or anything requiring a subscription to access.

Comment: are you guys using the errata or not? (for instance the unlimited encounter powers is fixed)

Comment: We're using the updates in the "compiled updates pdf" from WotC but we're not using anything that requires a subscription to access. (None of us has a subscription to the site)

Comment: Ok, so, errata yes. That's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Demigod is pretty darn good. It's still (even post errata), considered one of the best Epic Destinies that any character can take. The +2 to two stats, and regen are *just that good*.

However, if you want to go a different route, the other one you've chosen is well [rated](http://community.wizards.com/comment/16085496#comment-16085496) (though less than Demigod).

One you *may* qualify for being that you've got some MC Ranger going on is Deadly Trickster. If you don't qualify, you might be close enough to build for it (need 21 DEX or CHA and training in one of 4 skills).

It offers some very nice reroll, power recovery and denial options as the various features and I'd recommend it for your character if you qualify.